# sqlite3.exe needs a restart when a table structure is updated

Tags: sqlite

After I've launched *sqlite3.exe my_table*, I update the DB schema (add/remove columns) from the outside (for ex. PHP laravel in my case), then I check the table structure with `PRAGMA table_info(my_table)`: the schema isn't updated. If I close then relaunch *sqlite3.exe* I see the update.

Is it an expected behavior that *sqlite3.exe* needs to be restarted if the data structure has been changed from the outside ?

Comment: You need to make sure you commit all transactions from php

Comment: @mvp If it was about php transactions, I think that restarting sqlite3.exe would not help, but it does.

Answer (score 0):

Yep.
If data has been edited externally it needs to be reloaded into the program.

Comment: That doesn't seem very user-friendly to me. I can't conceive that there isn't a kind of feature that indicates a DB change and forces the reload.

Comment: i stopped working with this a while ago, but this was how it was. we did research and couldn't find anything.